# Python. Вызов декоратора внутри класса

Tags: python, декоратор

Общий пример

```
class TestClass: #класс

    def _bold(func): #функция
        def inner(): # обёртка wrapper
            print ("<b>")
            func() 
            print ("</b>")
        return inner

    @_bold #декоратор
    def hello(self): #функция, которую "вкладываем"
        print ("Hello")

#ВЫЗОВ
x = TestClass() 
x.hello()
```

Необходимо использование декоратора внутри класса, как это правильно сделать? И возможно ли создать метод внутри класса, который будет вызывать декоратор hello()? по типу:

```
def call_decorator(self):
    self.hello()
```

UPD: Вообщем-то разобрался

```
class TestClass:

    def _bold(func):
        def inner(self):
            print ("<b>")
            func(self)
            print ("</b>")
        return inner

    @_bold
    def hello(self):
        print ("Hello")

x = TestClass()
x.hello()
```

Вызов - банален:

```
def start_hello(self):
        self.hello()
```

Comment: Вам обязательно запихивать `def _bold` внутрь класса?

Comment: В чём у вас проблема с `call_decorator`?

Comment: Да, мне обязательно, что def _bold был внутри класса, я знаю, что можно метод вынести за пределы класса, но мне это не подходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class TestClass: #класс

    def _bold(func): #функция
        def inner(*args, **kwargs): # обёртка wrapper
            print ("<b>")
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            print ("</b>")
        return inner

    @_bold #декоратор
    def hello(self): #функция, которую "вкладываем"
        print ("Hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

Для тех кто задался вопросом "Куда засунуть self?".

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._text = "Наблюдаю за тем что ты делаешь..."

    @staticmethod
    def _test_decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            self = args[0]
            print(self._text)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @_test_decorator
    def print_name(self, name):
        print(name)

Test().print_name('Maksim')
```

Comment: Замечание в рамках проверки "первого ответа": Уточните, каким образом ваш ответ относится к вопросу автора.  В его вопросе "Куда засунуть self?" не звучало.

Comment: @Сергей Этот вопрос возникает если пытаться создать такой декоратор в виде статического метода. Лично я такой ответ и искал, спасибо его автору