# Можно ли объявить декоратор внутри класса так, чтобы доп аргументами шли другие методы?

Tags: python, классы, python-3.6

После изучения данного вопроса [Python. Вызов декоратора внутри класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768343/python-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)

Решил использовать данный метод, для написания декоратора внутри класса. 
Он проверяет значения одного метода и в зависимости от ответа либо выполняет доп метод либо выполняет. Вынести это все в отдельный метод не получится, так как подобную конструкцию необходимо применить ко всем остальным методам.
Но все равно лезут ошибки.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобными проблемами?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def _refresh(func1,func2,func3):
        def checker(self):
            if func2:
                func3
            func1
        return checker


    def switcher(self):
        return True

    def prep(self):
        self.m = 100

    def diver(self):
        self.m = self.m / 4

    @_refresh(switcher(), diver())
    def prep1(self):
        self.b=self.m/2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# функция, принимающая аргументы и возвращающая декоратор
def _refresh(func2, func3):

    # сам декоратор
    def decorator(func1):

        # функция-обертка, заменит собой декорируемую
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if func2(self):
                func3(self)
            func1(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # декоратор возвращает обертку
        return wrapper

    # возаращаем сам декоратор
    return decorator
```

только это не особо подходящий случай для использования декораторов

#### Upd:

Ах да, забыл упомянуть: применять нужно немного не так, как в вашем примере.

```py
@_refresh(switcher, diver)
def prep1(self):
    self.b=self.m/2
```

т.е. передавать в качестве аргументов сами функции, а не результат их выполнения.

Для большей гибкости можно сделать так:

```py
@_refresh(lambda self: self.switcher(), lambda self: self.diver())
def prep1(self):
    self.b=self.m/2
```

Ну и откомментировал заодно.

Comment: к сожалению, как по-другому проверять состояние переменной, которая может в любой момент измениться (проверить это можно только отдельным методом) и может повлиять на выполнение всех методов - пока не додумал :(

Comment: В хорошей программе не бывает неожиданностей. если переменная - поле класса, и ее могут менять извне, ее нужно оформить в виде сеттера, в котором кроме непосредственного изменения делать всю сопутствующую работу по поддержанию инварианта класса. Например, с помощью стандартного декоратора @property (информация есть [тут](https://python-scripts.com/decorators))